# Trouble installing packages with pip

Tags: python, pip

Not seen this anywhere and I'm new to Python so have no experience to fall back on!

I'm trying to install Spacy, and I've been struggle along with various errors (just installing pip was difficult enough!) but have finally gotten to at least an install bar, except I've now got an error I cannot dissect.

I am using python 3.8 and pip 20.1.1 on Windows 10.

```
C:\Users\user.name>pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org spacy
Collecting spacy
  Downloading spacy-2.3.2.tar.gz (5.9 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 5.9 MB 939 kB/s
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\user.name\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' 'c:\users\user.name\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\user.name\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-gcg12fxg\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org -- setuptools wheel 'cython>=0.25' 'cymem>=2.0.2,<2.1.0' 'preshed>=3.0.2,<3.1.0' 'murmurhash>=0.28.0,<1.1.0' thinc==7.4.1
       cwd: None
  Complete output (54 lines):
  Collecting setuptools
    Downloading setuptools-49.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (789 kB)
  Collecting wheel
    Downloading wheel-0.34.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
  Collecting cython>=0.25
    Downloading Cython-0.29.21-cp38-cp38-win32.whl (1.6 MB)
  Collecting cymem<2.1.0,>=2.0.2
    Downloading cymem-2.0.3.tar.gz (51 kB)
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: 'c:\users\user.name\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\user.name\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-deig3f1p\\cymem\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\user.name\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-deig3f1p\\cymem\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\user.name\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-vzld0jec'
           cwd: C:\Users\user.name\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-deig3f1p\cymem\
      Complete output (40 lines):
      WARNING: The wheel package is not available.
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1123)'))': /simple/wheel/
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1123)'))': /simple/wheel/
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1123)'))': /simple/wheel/
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1123)'))': /simple/wheel/
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1123)'))': /simple/wheel/
      ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement wheel<0.33.0,>=0.32.0 (from versions: none)
      ERROR: No matching distribution found for wheel<0.33.0,>=0.32.0
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "c:\users\user.name\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\installer.py", line 128, in fetch_build_egg
          subprocess.check_call(cmd)
        File "c:\users\user.name\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
          raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
      subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['c:\\users\\user.name\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32\\python.exe', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', 'C:\\Users\\TOM~1.COP\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpi_eitzs8', '--quiet', 'wheel<0.33.0,>=0.32.0']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

      During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\user.name\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-deig3f1p\cymem\setup.py", line 149, in <module>
          setup_package()
        File "C:\Users\user.name\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-deig3f1p\cymem\setup.py", line 110, in setup_package
          setup(
        File "c:\users\user.name\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 143, in setup
          _install_setup_requires(attrs)
        File "c:\users\user.name\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 138, in _install_setup_requires
          dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
        File "c:\users\user.name\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 695, in fetch_build_eggs
          resolved_dists = pkg_resources.working_set.resolve(
        File "c:\users\user.name\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 781, in resolve
          dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(
        File "c:\users\user.name\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1066, in best_match
          return self.obtain(req, installer)
        File "c:\users\user.name\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1078, in obtain
          return installer(requirement)
        File "c:\users\user.name\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 754, in fetch_build_egg
          return fetch_build_egg(self, req)
        File "c:\users\user.name\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\installer.py", line 130, in fetch_build_egg
          raise DistutilsError(str(e))
      distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Command '['c:\\users\\user.name\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32\\python.exe', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', 'C:\\Users\\TOM~1.COP\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpi_eitzs8', '--quiet', 'wheel<0.33.0,>=0.32.0']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\user.name\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' 'c:\users\user.name\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\user.name\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-gcg12fxg\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org -- setuptools wheel 'cython>=0.25' 'cymem>=2.0.2,<2.1.0' 'preshed>=3.0.2,<3.1.0' 'murmurhash>=0.28.0,<1.1.0' thinc==7.4.1 Check the logs for full command output.

C:\Users\user.name>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting SSL errors when running the regular pip install command?

```
pip install spacy
```

Comment: Yes, `WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1123)'))': /simple/spacy/
....
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement spacy (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for spacy` removing all the retry s for comment length

Comment: Try to upgrade your package installer sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade pip

Comment: Sudo is not recognised. In any case, pip upgrade worked as I would have expected and 20.1.1 is the latest version

Answer (score 0):

You can also try

```
python3 -m pip install spacy
```

Comment: Nothing happens, just starts a new cmd line